# Registering IUnitOfWork As service in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am going to implement repository pattern in my asp.net core mvc application , for that i am trying my hands on a simple demo application which include repository and Unit of Work concept.
**My First Repository**

```
public  interface ICustomerRepository
{
    bool Add();

    bool Update();

    bool Delete();

}
```

and

```
 public class CustomerRepository:ICustomerRepository
{
    public bool Add()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool Update()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Second Repository**

```
public interface IOrderRepository
    {
        bool Add();

        bool Update();

        bool Delete();
    }
```

and

```
public class OrderRepository:IOrderRepository
    {
        public bool Add()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool Update()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool Delete()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**IUnit Of Work**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IOrderRepository Order {get;}

    ICustomerRepository Customer { get; }

    void Save();
    void Cancel();
}
```

and

```
public class UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(IOrderRepository order, ICustomerRepository customer)
    {
        Order = order;
        Customer = customer;
    }

    public  IOrderRepository Order { get; }

    public  ICustomerRepository Customer { get; }
    public void Save() { }
    public void Cancel() { }
}
```

And in my controller ,

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        IUnitOfWork UW { get; }

        public HomeController(IUnitOfWork uw)
        {
            UW = uw;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            UW.Customer.Add();
            UW.Order.Update();
            UW.Save();

            return View();
        }
}
```

I will add more code later for dapper , but at least it should work wiyhout any error , but it give me error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CoreTS.Repository.UnitOfWork.IUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'CoreTS.Controllers.HomeController'.

Someone suggested me to add IUnitOfWork as service in startup.cs under ConfigureService Method, as

```
services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

And After Adding this another error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CoreTS.Repository.Order.IOrderRepository' while attempting to activate 'CoreTS.Repository.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork'.

To make it work i had to add other two repository also in startup.cs also

```
services.AddSingleton<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
```

If there going to be n number of repository than i have to add everyone of them in startup.cs (according to this code ), what is the solution for that.

So

1.] What does these errors means ?

2.] What will be the correct configuration here ?

3.] What is the way to not to add n number of repository as service here ?

Note: As a mentioned already , this is just to understand the flow of pattern , i will add code for Dapper or EF Core later in this

Comment: Is the `IUnitOfWork` a DB transaction wrapper for your repositories? If so, you wont want to register them as singletons.

Comment: yes , and if not singleton than what , AddTransient or AddScoped  ?

Comment: Realistically you want to have it as a transient as you possibly can have multiple transactions per user thread. With singleton every request would share the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does these errors means ?

These error means that you are using the services through constructor Dependency Injection but you have not registered those services to DI resolver.

> What will be the correct configuration here ?

What you have done is the correct way to resolve services.

> What is the way to not to add n number of repository as service here?

You can extend the `IServiceCollection` as follows in a separate file.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {

         services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
         services.AddSingleton<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
         services.AddSingleton<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();

         return services;
    }
}
```

Then in the startup class as follows:

```
services.AddCustomServices(Configuration);
```

Comment: Does this StartupExtension need to be in the root or i can put it anywhere in my Project ?

Comment: You can keep in anywhere in the project. Even in a separate project.

Comment: Excellent , but why you changed name from statupextension to servicecollectionExtension ?

Comment: Nothing will be affected with the name change. you can give any meaningful name.

Comment: So how it is flowing to startup.cs , i am keeping it in a seprate folder named Extensions

Comment: Yes! This is the best option. I am also doing so. You can separate service registrations with separate extension file in the Extensions folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188353/discussion-between-saurabh-and-tanvirarjel).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message is quite meaningful. The DI container has to resolve the instance of `IUnitOfWork` which has two dependencies that are injected into its ctor. So DI container has to resolve these two as well.

There is no built-in functionality in asp.net-core that allows you to register all your repositories using pattern matching or something like that. You could register all dependencies one by one or use 3rd party libraries.

With [Scrutor](https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/) you can do something like this:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
                    .FromAssemblyOf<OrderRepository>()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IRepository>())
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithSingletonLifetime());
```

Note that for it to work all repositories must implement `IRepository` interface (which can be empty)

Conclusion:
If it's only a few dependencies I'd probably register them one by one however if you plan to add N repositories later - use 3rd party libs.

Comment: ok , so what is the correct approach to apply UOW pattern here ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The constructor for HomeController takes an IUnitOfWork, so ASP.NET Core needs to know what instance to give it, that's why you specify it in ConfigureServices.  But, your UnitOfWork class' constructor takes an IOrderRepository and an ICustomerRepository, and ASP.NET Core needs to know what instances of those to supply, so you have to specify those in ConfigureServices as well.
2. I think the configuration you've ended up at is correct, as far as it goes, but it doesn't address your next question...
3. There's already a problem with your pattern without the ASP.NET Core dependency injection issues.  Your constructor for UnitOfWork takes 2 distinct parameters, one for each repository.  If you want to have N different repositories, that constructor no longer works.  Instead, maybe you need to introduce a "repository manager" class and just inject that into the constructor (add it in ConfigureServices too).  Then you need to devise a relationship between UnitOfWork and RepositoryManager that allows UnitOfWork to work with any specific repository.

Comment: A comment is always a nice accompaniment to a downvote.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question of how to *register* all dependencies when you have N repositories and you don't want to do it one by one...

Comment: sorry , but its not me , your 3rd point is valid , i m keeping them in a seprate file which is a startp extension

Comment: @Fabjan I don't think the OP ever uses the word _register_.  What do you mean by _register_?  For that matter, what does _N repositories_ mean?  Can N vary at runtime, should I have to modify source code when N changes, or can I just drop in a DLL with a new repository and expect it to work, etc?

Comment: @Martin Register means to call `services.Add<>...`. N is any number of dependencies for repositories. The OP has 2 and in his scenario it is static number. Other questions are even less relevant to the subject so...

Comment: @Fabjan Thank you for clarifying your earlier comment.  Clearly we each read the question quite differently.  Hopefully both our contributions will be valuable to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no service registered in the IoC container for `IUnitOfWork`/`IOrderRepository`. You solved this by registering these services using AddSingleton method.
2. Not sure what you mean by correct configuration, but using AddSingleton/AddTransient/AddScoped you are registering some classes as services in the IoC container. So when you inject something (for example into your HomeController), then you are using the interface mapped to some concrete implementation.
3. You have to register the service somehow, that is what you are doing with methods mentioned before. If you won't register it, it won't be resolved and you will get exceptions when trying to activate some other dependent services. If you want to register some services without doing it explicitely, you will have to scan the assembly and look for types that you want to register.